# IS VB.NET more Portable than C#?

Tags: c#, portability

My Computer Science Professor told me that VB.NET is more portable than C#. Is this true? I read that both C# and VB.NET are compiled to the same intermediate code.

Comment: Your Computer Science Professor doesn't seem to understand the fundamentals of the .NET platform.

Comment: Time to switch schools.

Comment: Every computer language is compiled to the same language... binairy language.

Comment: He made a mistake. Perhaps he meant it's easier for him.

Comment: I've heard worse professor opinions, like the idea that you should always code in Pascal and never in C, solely because C lets you alter the value of an index inside a loop.

Comment: It is certainly true, the notion of pointers is completely absent in Visual Basic.  The C# language requires a decked-out implementation of the CLR with full support for unverifiable code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd like to know how your professor justifies such a statement.  Yes, they both compile to the same IL.  Once compiled, there's no difference between the two.  It's also generally as easy to compile one as it is the other, since their respective compilers are generally packaged together.  I can't really think of any "portability" advantage of VB over C#.

Comment: @Shoban: Woohoo!  And just before I start a new job that I found on Stack Overflow Careers.  I'm _really_ enjoying this community :)

Comment: nice to hear that. Congrats and all the best.

Answer (score 7):

If by portable you mean will it run on more hardware and operating system platforms than C#, the answer is no.  VB uses the same runtime platform that C# does, and supports the same hardware and operating systems.

If by portable you mean it has better language interoperability, the answer is still no.  VB.NET has things like case insensitivity that make it *less* interoperable (within the .NET framework) than C#.

Answer (score 1):

C# is more portable. It can be used with the Mono project to be used on mac, iphone, etc. Last time I checked, you couldn't do that with VB.

Comment: I thought for sure that Mono had a VB compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The only way it would be more portable would be if the BASIC language in general somehow outlived C-style languages years down the road.  That's a dubious prospect at best.  I'd say that if not for the success of Visual Basic in the 1990's, BASIC would have been long gone from the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Portability is typically associated with the computer programming languages capability of being compiled in different hardware platforms with minimal or no changes to the original source code. Take the C language as an example.

Vb.net and C# are not native languages and can hardly be associated with being portable, UNLESS the .net framework could be run on systems other than windows and then your programs could be compiled AND run on those other systems; both languages would be considered portable then. As long as they can only be compiled and run through the .net framework which only runs on windows, what portability have we got here?

Ask your professor where has he seen a vb.net or c# program ported to other computer systems?

Good luck!